# Redis string or sets?

Tags: string, redis, set

I want to store person & food pairs, person eats food in 5 minutes, so I need to expire the key. So I have 2 ways to do that, string or sets:

```
1. setex person:tommy:food:chicken 300 anything
   setex person:tommy:food:chip 300 anything
   ...

2. sadd person:tommy chicken chip
   expire person:tommy 300
```

Which is better? Or is there other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the second option.  My reasons being:

1. Since there is no other information attached to entries, there is no reason to give each item its own key (this would be different if each item needed to store a hash of information, for example).
2. You can find out how many food items are linked to a person ([`SCARD`](http://redis.io/commands/scard)) without creating another key.
3. You have all of the other [set functions](http://redis.io/commands#set) available to you if you need to manipulate or compare several sets to each other.
4. If you read the documentation on [how redis expires keys](http://redis.io/commands/expire), you notice that Redis has an active approach to expiring keys.  Using the second option's design, it is guaranteed that all food data associated with someone will be removed at the same time, when the key expiration method runs.

To some degree, this question seems analogous to using individual variables in a programming language, as opposed to an array:

```
a = 3, b = 5, c = 7
sum = a + b + c
```

versus

```
items = [3, 5, 7]
sum = sum(items)
```

Comment: The set approach is also advantageous if the people in question are gluttons - keeping multiple person:food pairs in separate keys is more expensive compared to a single person:foods set in terms of RAM.

Comment: The only one thing I want to choose string is the way to set expiration is very simple. I just create and set expire for every key. If I use sets, how can I set its expiration only once, at the first time I create it without race condition?

Comment: More information: new food will be added at any time.